# How can sort and categorize an array of dictionaries as alphabetically in the UITableView as sections in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on swift and I have an array of dictionaries like,

> [ {"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Abdullah, "email":
>   spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Jaleel, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mr}, {"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Catherine,
>   "email": spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Rose, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mrs}, {"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Alok, "email":
>   spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Raj, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mr}, {"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Darwin, "email":
>   spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Jose, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mr}].

Here I want to list all speakers in UITableView as alphabetically on the basis of first_name. I can sort the array of dictionaries as alphabetically, but the problem is I want to show the alphabets in the UITableViewSection and that section only contains the names starting with that alphabet only(like contact screen of iPhone).

[image]
So can i convert the array of dictionary as follows,

> { a: [{"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Abdullah, "email":
>   spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Jaleel, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mr}, {"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Alok, "email":
>   spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Raj, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mr}], c: [{"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Catherine,
>   "email": spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Rose, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mrs}], d:[{"added": 2017-12-24, "first_name": Darwin,
>   "email": spaeker1@example.com, "Last_name": Jose, "place": India,
>   "salutation":Mr}] }.

Is it possible to group the array of dictionary as above? Otherwise how can list all the speakers as alphabetically in UITableViewSection. Please help me.

Comment: You can loop through the dictionary then prepare the desired dictionary

Comment: *I'm working on swift and I have an array of dictionaries like..* -- You sure you are using Swift?  I'm going to go out on a limb and state that the dictionary you posted is not legal syntax in ANY language currently in existence.

Comment: Parse to proper object, do not work with dictionary like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to group the array of dictionary as above?

```
let users = [
    ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Abdullah", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "salutation": "Mr"],
    ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Catherine", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "salutation": "Mrs"],
    ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Alok", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "salutation": "Mr"],
    ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Darwin", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "salutation": "Mr"]
]

func firstCharOfFirstName(_ aDict: [String:String]) -> Character {
    return aDict["first_name"]!.first!
}

let groupedUsers = Dictionary(grouping: users, by: firstCharOfFirstName)
print(groupedUsers)

--output:--
["C": 
[["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Catherine", "salutation": "Mrs"]], 
"D": 
[["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Darwin", "salutation": "Mr"]], 
"A": 
[["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Abdullah", "salutation": "Mr"],  
["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Alok", "salutation": "Mr"]]]
```

Then you can sort each group as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the array of dictionary then prepare the result.

**Code**

```
let dict = [ ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Abdullah", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"], ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Catherine", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mrs"], ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Alok", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"], ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Darwin", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"]]

var result: [String:[[String:String]]] = [:]
for d in dict {
   var tempContactArray: [[String:String]] = []
   let firstName = d["first_name"]?.lowercased()
   let firstChar = firstName![0]
   if let data = result[firstChar] {
       tempContactArray = data
   }
   tempContactArray.append(d)
   result[firstChar] = tempContactArray
}
let sortedKeysAndValues = result.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })

print(sortedKeysAndValues)
```

Write an extension of string as

```
extension String {
subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)] as Character)
}
```

}

**Output of sortedKeysAndValues**

```
[(key: "a", value: [["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Abdullah", "salutation": "Mr"], ["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Alok", "salutation": "Mr"]]), (key: "c", value: [["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Catherine", "salutation": "Mrs"]]), (key: "d", value: [["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Darwin", "salutation": "Mr"]])]
```

You cannot sort a dictionary as dictionary is an unordered collection of elements. So if you want to sort then it has to be array.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might find useful using a combo of `reduce`+`sorted`, in this way you can group your dictionaries alphabetically, adding first character of `first_name` as key:

**Swift 3.0**

```
let arrayOfDict = [ ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Abdullah", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"],["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Catherine", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mrs"],["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Alok", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"],["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Darwin", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"]]

var result = arrayOfDict.reduce([String: [[String:Any]]]()) { res, element in
  var mutableRes = res
  if let firstLetter = element["first_name"]?.characters.prefix(0) {
    let initial = String(describing: firstLetter).lowercased()
    if mutableRes[initial] == nil {
      mutableRes[initial] = [[String:Any]]()
    }
    mutableRes[initial]?.append(element)
  }
  return mutableRes
}.sorted { return $0.key < $1.key }
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let arrayOfDict = [ ["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Abdullah", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"],["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Catherine", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mrs"],["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Alok", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"],["added": "2017-12-24", "first_name": "Darwin", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "salutation":"Mr"]]

let result = arrayOfDict.reduce(into: [String: [[String:Any]]]()) { result, element in
  if let firstLetter = element["first_name"]?.first {
    let initial = String(describing: firstLetter).lowercased()
      result[initial, default: [[String:Any]]() ].append(element)
    }}.sorted { return $0.key < $1.key }
print(result)
```

final result will be:

```
[(key: "a", value: [["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Jaleel", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Abdullah", "salutation": "Mr"], ["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Raj", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Alok", "salutation": "Mr"]]), (key: "c", value: [["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Rose", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Catherine", "salutation": "Mrs"]]), (key: "d", value: [["added": "2017-12-24", "Last_name": "Jose", "place": "India", "email": "spaeker1@example.com", "first_name": "Darwin", "salutation": "Mr"]])]
```

Comment: For Swift 4, I am getting error - Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: @Andrea Mugnaini How can we assign keys and values of result in UITableViewController as section and cell label text?